# Adding a background image to the header

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to display a photo as background image for a Drupal 7.7 website.

After reading [a doc on subthemes](http://drupal.org/node/225125), I have created a directory called "pasture" in the same directory where "bartik" resides (i.e. in ~/public_html/drupal/themes/pasture).

- I have created the pasture.info file.

```
name = pasture
base theme = Bartik
stylesheets[all][] = pasture.css
files[] = pasture.jpg
core = 7.x
```

- I have created the pasture.css file.

```
#header {
        background:url(/drupal/themes/pasture/pasture.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}
```

- I have saved a public domain image as pasture.jpg. The image is the following one.

[image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, [my site](http://simplex.ru/drupal) appears completely broken, after I activate that theme, and I see numerous warnings:

> Notice: Undefined index: Bartik in method drupal_theme_initialize() (line 98 inf file /usr/www/users/simplex/drupal/includes/theme.inc).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in method phptemplate_init() (line 12 in file /usr/www/users/simplex/drupal/themes/engines/phptemplate/phptemplate.engine).

Comment: For who doesn't understand Russian, is "в функции" the name of the property?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question, sorry

Comment: Just curious ... is that files[] parameter used for including images? Have you tried removing it? http://drupal.org/node/171205 And ensure Bartik is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment, but some remarks

1. remove the files[] = pasture.jpg line, it isn't needed
2. you may enable your base theme, but it isn't necessary
3. put your own themes (modules) under /sites/all/themes or /sites/default/themes, don not put them inside /themes (/modules), if this directory doesn't exist, just create them

Question, does your site works when using the Bartik theme?

Comment: Site works using the Bartik theme (production: simplex.ru, development: simplex.ru/drupal) and it seems to me that 3) is wrong because I can see my theme among Themes in simplex.ru/drupal/admin/appearance/settings which probably means my custom sub-theme is being found by Drupal.

Comment: you can see the themes inside /themes, it is best practice to put all custom/downloaded things inside sites/all